# MySQL and JDBC PreparedStatement using Select

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets, jdbc

I'm getting this exception when I try to run the program

> Exception
>   Caughtcom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? and pass
>   =?' at line 1

When I hard code values I get the proper result. For eg: `SELECT name, pass from servlettutorial.logintable where name = 'Bill' and pass = 'Gates'` runs perfectly fine.

What could be wrong with the SQL syntax in the program above?

```
try{
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/servlettutorial?"
                      + "user=root&password=carinov");

              String sql = "SELECT name, pass from servlettutorial.logintable where name = ? and pass = ?";
              PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

              stmt.setString(1, serv_name); 
              stmt.setString(2,serv_pass);

              ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

              while (rs.next()) {

                    String d_name = rs.getString("name");
                    String d_pass = rs.getString("pass");

                    if(d_name.equals(serv_name) && (d_pass.equals(serv_pass)))
                    {
                            found_match=1;
                            break;
                    }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass the SQL query to `executeQuery()`, since the `PreparedStatement` already contains the query and the parameters.

change

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)
```

to

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It solved the problem :)

Comment: @Cafe You're welcome